# Random padding above list?

Tags: html, css

look at http://ballpointradio.com/new/index.php. Do you see above the Recent Tracks there's sort of padding? How do I get rid of this?

Thanks,
Sam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<div class="content_wide">` is taking up the full width of `<div id="content">`, which is why it looks like `<div class="content_right">` has padding above it. In fact it is just following normal behavior and appearing below divs that are listed before it in the page's structure.

To get around this you could put `<div class="content_inside">` in `<div class="content_left">` and get rid of `<div class="content_wide">`.

Answer (score 0):

In your style for `#content` there is `padding-top:10px` causing that padding. You should remove that eg:

```
#content {
  height:auto !important;
  margin-bottom:-100px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  min-height:50%;
  padding-top:10px; /* <- remove this line */
  text-align:left;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  width:960px;
}
```